# How can I remove escaping from a RegExp pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to simplify input for a particular regex for my users. A simple example of the regex might be

```
\b(C|C\+\+|Java)\b
```

I'm now giving the user the option of appending another branch at the end of the regex by inputting the raw string into a `<input type="text">` field. The branch will be interpreted literally, so I need to escape it. I've used https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593661/785663 to get `RegExp.quote` to do this. I then store the complete regex in a database.

Now, when I retrieve the regex from the database and split it back up and display the branches to the user, I need to remove all the escape characters again. Is there some pre-made function for this or do I need to roll my own?

Yes, I know I ought to replace this with a list of strings to search for. But this only a part of a larger (regex based) picture.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you don't need to remove escaped characters. If you are displaying the regex, display the escaped characters along with it. If you are displaying match, the match will only match the characters and will not contain escape sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I've been unclear. This is not about actually **using** the regex, I just store the regex pattern and need to display it sans the escaping necessary to actually apply it (elsewhere).

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to store the raw string in the database and create the regular expression on-the-fly when it is needed. You have to compile the patterns from the database anyway, before they can be applied. So an additional string concatenation won't harm the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal solution is to change your design: store the unescaped regex, then only escape it when you actually use it.  That way you don't have to worry about this messy business of converting it back and forth all the time.

If you use this regex a lot and are worried about the overhead of having to escape it all the time, then store *both* the unescaped and escaped versions.  Update both whenever the user makes a change.

p.s. Allowing user-entered regexes may make your site [vulnerable to attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS). *(Update: Though in this case it is less likely to be a problem, since you are only allowing literal strings)*

Comment: As others have suggested, I'm going with a design change. Saves me a bunch of headaches, too.